# SQL Query: insert if not already exists from 2 tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to insert rows if they don't exist (for specific values) in this table.

My table where I insert is insertTable:

```
date (date)
created (datetime)
category (varchar)
companyId (int)
price (decimal 6,3)
```

I select my rows from an inner join between two tables doing :

```
declare @currentDateTime datetime = getDate()
declare @currentDate date = getDate()
INSERT INTO insertTable (date, created, category, companyId, price)
SELECT @currentDate, @currentDateTime, '30 Day', company.companyId, product.price
FROM product 
INNER JOIN company
ON product.companyid = company.companyid
WHERE product.price >= 0.31 AND ... other conditions on company fields ...
AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT  * FROM insertTable WHERE insertTable.price  = product.price
                    AND insertTable.date = @currentDateTime 
                    AND insertTable.companyid = product.companyid
                    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(insertTable.category)) = '30 Day'
    )
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Thanks

--edited after Gordon Linoff Comment. 
I insert the result of that select in my insertTable.
My issue is that I get duplicates in insertTable.

If insertTable had

```
2014-09-26 | 2014-09-26 02:25:00 | 30 Day | 32650 | 0.600
```

My select will return something like

```
2014-09-26 | 2014-09-26 02:36:00 | 30 Day | 32650 | 0.600
```

However I already have that companyID and price in the insert table

Comment: I had a feeling I was missing something in my post... I edited to explain my problem

Comment: Do you know about [**`MERGE`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)? Sounds like a good case for one of those. From MSDN: _"Performs […] operations on a target table based on the results of a join with a source table. For example, you can synchronize two tables by inserting, updating, or deleting rows in one table based on differences found in the other table."_

Comment: @stakx Thanks stakx. Rajesh proposed that solution that i did not know about. It is discussed on this page. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem statement cannot be accurate
rate is not defined

you are missing created
and you are comparing date to @currentDateTime

```
SELECT @currentDate, @currentDateTime, '30 Day'
     , company.companyId, product.price
  FROM product 
  JOIN company
    ON product.companyid = company.companyid
   and product.price >= 0.31 AND ... other conditions on company fields ...
AND NOT EXISTS(
               SELECT  * 
                 FROM insertTable 
                WHERE insertTable.date = @currentDate 
                --AND insertTable.created = @currentDateTime
                  AND insertTable.price  = product.price
                  AND insertTable.companyid = product.companyid
                  AND LTRIM(RTRIM(insertTable.category)) = '30 Day'
               )
```

Comment: i don't mind to compare by created because i already compare by date. Created and date share the same date, except that created specifies the time. Nevertheless you were right for comparing date to @currentDateTime

Answer (score 1):

I think you must modify your subquery in `NOT EXISTS`: `@currentDateTime` change to `@currentDate` and `rate.companyid` change to `company.companyid` (because when insert `insertTable.date` gets value of `@currentDate` and `insertTable.companyid` gets value of `company.companyid`):

```
...
AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT  * FROM insertTable WHERE insertTable.price  = product.price
                    AND insertTable.date = @currentDate 
                    AND insertTable.companyid = company.companyid
                    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(insertTable.category)) = '30 Day'
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Rimas. Yeah rate.company i meant company.companyid. That was a mistake typing that. But the currentdatetime to currentdate was the issue. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the EXISTS function this way.  I think you probably need to do a LEFT JOIN to the insertTable table and then add a "iT.Price IS NULL" to your WHERE clause.  (This assumes Price is never actually NULL on your insertTable.)

Answer (score 0):

you need a correlated subquery, not a join in the subquery.

It is even better to use **MERGE** statement http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

```
declare @currentDateTime datetime = getDate()
declare @currentDate date = getDate()
INSERT INTO insertTable (date, created, category, companyId, price)
SELECT @currentDate, @currentDateTime, '30 Day', company.companyId, product.price
FROM product 
INNER JOIN company
ON product.companyid = company.companyid
WHERE product.price >= 0.31 AND ... other conditions on company fields ...
AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT  1 FROM insertTable WHERE insertTable.price  = product.price
                    AND insertTable.date = @currentDate
                    AND insertTable.companyid = company.companyid
                    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(insertTable.category)) = '30 Day'
    )
```

EDIT:

You can do the same with MERGE like below

```
MERGE insertTable as target
USING ( SELECT @currentDate, 
           @currentDateTime,
               '30 Day', 
               company.companyId, 
               product.price
        FROM INNER JOIN company
    ON product.companyid = company.companyid
    WHERE product.price >= 0.31 AND ... other conditions on company fields ...
 ) as source ( currentDate, currentDateTime, category, companyid, price)
ON target.price = source.price
AND target.date = source.currentDate
and target.companyid = source.companyid
and LTRIM(RTRIM(target.category)) = '30 Day'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (date, created, category, companyId, price)
    VALUES (source.currentDate, source.currentDatetime, source.category, source.companyId, source.price)
```

Comment: I am not sure about how to implement that MERGE statement. I am not familiar with MERGE at all. And I don't see it used in your answer.

Comment: @Greg, updated with MERGE statement. you can either update or insert based on condition easily with merge.

Comment: Thank you for completing your answer. This seems to be appropriate for my situation. Since I already coded my query with not exists I might stick to that. Except if that makes a big difference somehow?

Comment: @Greg, sure, probably you can try MERGE for the future SQL.